# How do I call a function inside the function that you are calling to [PYTHON]

Tags: python

How do I call a function inside the function that you are calling to?

Here is an example to make this clearer for you...

```
def foo():
    bar = input("Are you cool?")

    if bar.lower() == "yes":
        print("Liar")
        foo()

    if bar.lower() == "no":
        print("Good, your not a Liar")
        exit()

    else:
        print("Error, try again...")
        foo()

 foo()
```

Comment: This is called recursion and it looks like you did it successfully, although this isn't a good application for recursion.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have now? How is your current output different than your expected output?

Comment: @ggorlen What is recursion, is it just repeating?

Comment: @Sago recursion is when a function calls itself

Comment: @Sago, [here's an example of recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082740/how-do-i-call-a-function-inside-the-function-that-you-are-calling-to-python). Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: What you are doing is recursion. You can also do this implement with a while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def foo():
    return input("Are you cool?")

def checkCoolness():
    while True:
        if foo() == "Yes":
            print("Doubt it..")
            foo()
        else:
            print("Don't say that!")
            return
checkCoolness()
```

Try this. It's better than recursion because no matter how many times you call foo() you won't be adding a duplicate function to the stack.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually completely valid, and this works. What you are doing is called a recursion, which is essentially when a function calls itself. A lot more information can be found here: [this](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/53a21f5d7c82cad00200024d#:%7E:text=Answer%2053e550d39c4e9d53dc000182&text=Calling%20a%20function%20inside%20of,printing%20out%20the%20fibonacci%20series.) Although this may not be a good application for it, it certainly works.